# Change layout of next item in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm beginner android developer.

I need to change layout of next item in listview by clicking button on current item. I don't understand how to access next item.

So, how to change layout of next item?

Here is my code:

Adapter class

```
public class StepsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_FIRST = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_NEXT = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 2;

    private List<String> steps;
    private Context mContext;

    public StepsAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mContext = context;
        steps = objects;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public final Button btnDone;
        public final TextView txtView;
        public final TextView txtViewMain;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            btnDone = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.right);
            txtView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_step_textview_finish);
            txtViewMain = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_step_textview);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position != 0) ? VIEW_TYPE_FIRST : VIEW_TYPE_NEXT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        int layoutId = -1;
        switch (viewType){
            case VIEW_TYPE_FIRST: {
                layoutId = R.layout.list_item_step;
                break;
            }
            case VIEW_TYPE_NEXT: {
                layoutId = R.layout.list_item_first_step;
                break;
            }
        }
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.txtViewMain.setText(steps.get(position));

        viewHolder.btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
                ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
                int listVCount = listView.getCount();
                int position = listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

                viewHolder.txtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.btnDone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                String textFinishStep = "Passed step " + (position + 1) + " : " + viewHolder.txtViewMain.getText();
                viewHolder.txtView.setText(textFinishStep);
                viewHolder.txtViewMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your StepsAdapter take one field as follows

```
private int cposition=-1;
```

and take one method also as follows

```
public void setPosition(int cposition){
    this.cposition=cposition;
}
```

and in

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            adapter.setPosition(position);
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
        }
    });
```

and in

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
       if(cposition!=-1&&position=cposition+1){
             //change list item layout here
              cposition=-1;
        }
 }
```

Hope this will helps you.